# How to launch react-native application from service with parameters?

Tags: android, react-native

When I get a notification, I open my application like this (In my service):

```
Intent intent = new Intent("fcm.ACTION.HELLO");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("param1","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

How can i read the parameter in index.android.js?

That you

Answer (score 0):

I did it with this function:

```
FCM.getInitialNotification().then(notif=>console.log(notif));
```